# Jenkinsfile parallel stages - One Says Paused While Running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile which has the following section:

```
parallel {
    stage('Tests 1') {
        agent any
        steps {
            sh "bash do_tests_1.sh"
        }
    }
    stage('Tests 2') {
        agent any
        steps {
            sh "bash do_tests_2.sh"
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is running, and the parallel jobs run simultaneously as they are supposed to, but the problem is that in the pipeline dashboard for the build, the job `Tests 2` runs with a progress bar and then says complete, but `Tests 1` says paused and does not have a progress bar even though I can see that it is running in the console logs.

Is there something special that would have to be done for `Tests 1` to have a status bar and say running? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Standard jenkins UI can't show you steps running in parallel, only one by one.

Install Blue Ocean plugins, which bring new UI to pipeline jobs, and you will see these parallel steps in UI.